# Updating all the fields in a table using conditions in CakePhp

Tags: sql-update, cakephp-1.3, update-all

I have a table with some fields i want to update all the colums in a particular row, how we can do this?

I want to update this array of data into the table

```
                 $travel_details=array(
                'userprofile_id'=>$upid,
                'day'=>$data['day'],
                'dayNumeric'=>$daynum,
                'morning_route'=>$morning_route,
                'morning_time'=>$morning_time,
                'evening_route'=>$evening_route,
                'evening_time'=>$evening_time,
                'traveller' =>$traveller
            );
```

i use one code with some conditions

```
          $this->Singleroute->updateAll($travel_details,array('Singleroute.userprofile_id'=>$upid,'Singleroute.daynumeric'=>$daynum,
            'Singleroute.day'=>$data['day']));
```

but this code is not working..is there any way to update al;l the fields in a row?
[image: this is the table structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$travel_details should be like this

```
$travel_details['Singleroute']=array(
                'userprofile_id'=>$upid,
                'day'=>$data['day'],
                'dayNumeric'=>$daynum,
                'morning_route'=>$morning_route,
                'morning_time'=>$morning_time,
                'evening_route'=>$evening_route,
                'evening_time'=>$evening_time,
                'traveller' =>$traveller
            );
```

you need to specify the model in fields array.
NOw run your query

```
$this->Singleroute->updateAll($travel_details,array('Singleroute.userprofile_id'=>$upid,'Singleroute.daynumeric'=>$daynum,
            'Singleroute.day'=>$data['day']));
```

Read more for saving data here
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#saving-your-data